# alasql returning incorrect value for Date field

Tags: javascript, csv, alasql

I am using the below code to read the excel data using ALASQL

```
alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{headers:true})', [event], function (data) {       
        excelData = data;
    });
```

This works for all the fields except the date field

The date field has values like below

```
09/08/18
9/21/2018
```

and the ALASQL returns the value as

```
43351
43364
```

How do I get the actual value? or is there a way to change `43351` to `09/08/18` ?

Comment: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/369

Answer (score 1):

The other answer has two days difference with this

```js
const convertDateExcel = (excelTimestamp) => {
  // 1. Subtract number of days between Jan 1, 1900 and Jan 1, 1970, plus 1 (Google "excel leap year bug")
  // 2. Convert to milliseconds.
  const secondsInDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
  const excelEpoch = new Date(1899, 11, 31);
  const excelEpochAsUnixTimestamp = excelEpoch.getTime();
  const missingLeapYearDay = secondsInDay * 1000;
  const delta = excelEpochAsUnixTimestamp - missingLeapYearDay;
  const excelTimestampAsUnixTimestamp = excelTimestamp * secondsInDay * 1000;
  const parsed = excelTimestampAsUnixTimestamp + delta;
  return isNaN(parsed) ? null : new Date(parsed);
};

console.log(
  convertDateExcel(43351) // According to other answer 2018-09-09 WITH tz offset
);
console.log(
  convertDateExcel(37988) // Supposedly 2004-01-02 WITH tz offset
);

// Same dates with other calculation are 2 days off

const getJsDateFromExcel = excelDate => new Date((excelDate - (25567 + 1)) * 86400 * 1000);

console.log(
  getJsDateFromExcel(43351) // According to other answer 2018-09-09 WITH tz offset
);
console.log(
  getJsDateFromExcel(37988) // Supposedly 2004-01-02 WITH tz offset
);
```

https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/369

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that I have convert to Excel to Javascript Date and I used the below function
This worked for MM/DD/YYYY format.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/christopherscott/2782634) is where I found this snippet

```js
function getJsDateFromExcel1(excelDate) {
  // JavaScript dates can be constructed by passing milliseconds
  // since the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970) example: new Date(12312512312);
  // 1. Subtract number of days between Jan 1, 1900 and Jan 1, 1970, plus 1 (Google "excel leap year bug")             
  // 2. Convert to milliseconds.
  return new Date((excelDate - (25567 + 1)) * 86400 * 1000);
}
console.log(
  getJsDateFromExcel1(43351)
);
```